# Can't send e-mails using python script on digital ocean droplet

Tags: python-3.x, smtp, office365, digital-ocean, smtp-auth

I am trying to send e-mails from a production server located on a digital ocean droplet using a office 356 mail server.

The operation executes correctly when I execute the python script on my test server (located on my mac) but fails with code 500 when on the production server.

I am using this code to achieve this:

```
def __init__(self, from_address="some@mail.com", from_password="somePassword",
             smtp_server="smtp.office365.com", smtp_port=587):
    self.from_address = from_address
    self.from_password = from_password
    self.smtp_server = smtp_server
    self.smtp_port = smtp_port

def send_mail(self, recipients, subject, message, project_id, pdf_files):
    client_id = ProjectClient.query.filter_by(project_id=project_id).first().client_id
    client = Client.query.filter_by(client_id=client_id).first()
    server = smtplib.SMTP(self.smtp_server, self.smtp_port)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(self.from_address, self.from_password)
```

...

```
    try:
        server.sendmail(self.from_address, recipients, message_body.as_string())
```

I am getting this error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 730, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 721, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 627, in auth
    initial_response = (authobject() if initial_response_ok else None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 664, in auth_login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (500, b"5.3.3 Unrecognized command 'cmFwcG9ydEBza2ltbWVsZnJpdC5kaw==' [AM5PR0701CA0011.eurprd07.prod.outlook.com]")
```

Stuff that I tried:

- Opened port 587 on the production server
- Contacted Office support to add the production server IP adress to the trusted list

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed by updating python to 3.5.1 (from 3.5.0).